# How can I make the styling I apply to nodes show for other users accessing the same data store in Graphileon?

Tags: graphileon

We are experimenting with using Graphileon to create a database of related terms. To do this, we are accessing a data store located on a server. We are able to see nodes and relationships that are added by other users, but the styling applied to these nodes is not carrying over.

Is there a way to make the styling universal for the entire data store and anyone accessing it? Or is any styling of nodes and relationships specific to the user who configured it?

Answer (score 0):

In principle styling is specific to the user. Since you are having multiple users, you are probably not using the personal edition. Can you confirm this?